# r- load a function from a directory outside the enviroment

Tags: r, function, path, load

I need to load a function that it's save in another directory and not in the enviroment I'm working in.

The original code was:

```
load("func1.RData",.GlobalEnv)
```

I tried:

```
load("func1.RData","C:/Users/Gaby/r/function/")
```

I get the following error:

> Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the
>   connection In addition: Warning message: In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes
>   = TRUE) :   cannot open compressed file 'func1.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

How can I point too the directory where the functions is wothout having to change the enviroment path?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the second argument to `load`.

Comment: What is your current working directory (output of `getwd()`)?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a full path.

```
load("C:/Users/Gaby/r/function/func1.RData")
```

or, laternatively, assuming your workspace is in `/Gaby`.

```
load("./function/func1.RData")
```

Comment: What about adding the option to go "up" a directory too... `load("../func1.RData")` if I need to navigate one folder outside of my current working directory?

Comment: You know you're free to improve my answer any day of the week, @AnandaMahto. :)